# Graph connection not displayed if there is no referential foreign key constraint

Tags: schemacrawler

I have tables in database postgres in which some tables does not have explicit foreign key referential contraints.

When I run schema crawler it does not generate graph connection for parent or child connection tables.

Is there any suport for namebased or columnname matching algo  support to recommend possible matching cols from different table to generate graph with some sort of scoring/ranking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/) can infer associations between columns if commonly used naming conventions are followed, and even if there are no foreign keys specified. Please take a look at the documentation on [weak associations](https://www.schemacrawler.com/weak-associations.html).

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)